# How can I use Live Server extension on VSCode with Local by FlyWheel to display php pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, flywheel

I was using local by flywheel and was creating php files and having them display.
Now it will not let me go live and brings me to a directory when I click "Go Live" in VS code.
I want to use 'Local by FlyWheel' in order to not introduce further complications by involving other methods. I need it to display the page and was told that it would and it did for a few days.
I am on a Windows PC. Please help.

I tried opening the admin page on 'local by flywheel' and signing in before trying to go Live.
I have messed around with extensions.
I am sort of a noob and want to use php with wordpress and the answers on YouTube are not there or present alternative methods.